# not able to run in chrome

Tags: selenium-rc

iam not able to run selenium rc with chrome.it runs fine in
firefox.Any one sucessful in running in chrome browser?

Comment: What error do you get? Please supply the code you use to start RC i.e. the seleniumId = new DefaultSelenium( "localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", ... snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These links will help:

- [Sauce Labs: Available browsers](http://saucelabs.com/docs/sauce-ondemand/browsers)
- [Google Groups: Selenium Users > Browser Strings](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/41fedc35b98b6c8a?pli=1)

These are Browser Strings are available:

- *firefox
- *mock
- *firefoxproxy
- *pifirefox
- *chrome
- *iexploreproxy
- *iexplore
- *firefox3
- *safariproxy
- *googlechrome
- *konqueror
- *firefox2
- *safari
- *piiexplore
- *firefoxchrome
- *opera
- *iehta
- *custom

*googlechrome

This is Google Chrome and not to be confused with *chrome which is 
actually Firefox.

*chrome

This one is a little confusing. The 'chrome' of a web browser is the 
usable space for the web page. That is, if the display is 1024x768, 
the chrome will be smaller. The title, menu, toolbars, status bar, 
etc. will reduce the usable space, i.e. the chrome. Google Chrome was 
called Chrome because one of the main goals was to maximize the 
chrome. Selenium was using the keyword *chrome before Google Chrome 
and it was using it for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using *googlechrome as the browser string?  If so, you need to be using 2.0a6.  Chrome is utterly broken in 1.0.3 and 2.0a7.